# Select @@identity while inserting possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this query which doesn't run correctly but it shows what I am trying to achieve:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (first_name, last_name, email, password_encrypt)

    VALUES
    (
    @first_name,@last_name,@email,
    EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('CertificateName'), @password_encrypt, 1, HashBytes('SHA1', CONVERT( varbinary, Output Inserted.UserID)))
    )
```

I would like to get the last inserted value produced by this insert statement and pass it where the Output Inserted.UserID is. How can that be done?

I can do this in two steps by selecting @@identity after the insert and then update the password column in the table. But I would love to do this in one go if it is possible at all.

My encryption is based on this article from Microsoft. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx
Thanks.

Comment: read about stored procedures, they will help you

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Marc_s, getting the scope identity is not my only goal. I want to get it while inserting. I tried scope_identity where the Output Inserted.UserID is now. It doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTPUT clause doesn't have any data for Inserted.* until after the insert has occurred. You will have to perform the insert first. If you try to work around it by nesting the INSERT into an UPDATE or MERGE query, SQL will give an error that it doesn't support that either.

One option is @@identity like you say. Another is to consider using the SEQUENCE object to define UserID. Its advantage in this case is that you can generate a UserID prior to the insert, and just like IDENTITY, there is no potential for conflict.

Comment: Nicholai, just to confirm. So you are saying that I need to do this in two steps right? First insert then update? I have tried and this type of solution works. The problem is I need to mark my password_encrypt column as nullable while it is actually can't be null.

Comment: That is correct. The identity doesn't exist until the row has been written. I recommend either using the Sequence object, or setting a temporary password during insert, and then updating it in a second step.